# Uniqueness of an issue in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am working on an application that uses sonarqube api to find all the issues created for a project. the api I am currently using is: issues/search?componentRoots={projectKey}. When I fetch all the issues, I am saving all these issues to my db. My question is, how is an issue unique for a project? My first thought was that the issueKey is supposed to be unique for an issue but after doing some tests, this was not the case. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not creating your own unique key for your database? You can also have a look in the SonarQube database to find the key (if exists).

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is wrong : issue#key is unique, so you can safely use it.